# Increasing maximum response size from ASP.NET Page Method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've got a page method on an ASPX page that gets called by a jQuery AJAX POST request. When I try to return too many results, the request fails. Is there a web.config setting or class attribute I can use to increase the default maximum response size?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am assuming you are returning JSON?

You can adjust the JSON response size in the web.config with:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>  
             <webServices>                                                   
                 <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />                 
             </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Doing a quick search, it looks like the default size is  102400.

> maxJsonLength Optional attribute.
>
> Configures the maximum length of the
>   JSON string (the maximum number of
>   UTF-8 characters).
>
> The default length is 102400.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513882(v=vs.90))